# Any alternative to window.history.back() as it repeats the visited page every time I go back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs, I have 3 pages, page1.html, page2.html, page3.html and have a function goback() which is

```
$scope.goback = function() {
    $window.history.back();
}
```

When I visit page1, page2, page3 and then again from page1,2,3 and again page1,2,3 and at last if I go back everyage repeats. means to say page3 then page 2 then page 1 and then again page3, 2, 1 and again page3, 2, 1.

I don't want to repeat these pages, if I press on goback(), it should go to page3, 2, 1 and then home.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can clear page history on Page1 so it won't go back to Page3.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are using `$window.history.back();` then it will go through all your history.
It is good but if you dont want to go back like this then use `data-ui-sref=""`, so that you will return on desire page.
And if you want to go back on the basis of condition then add conditions like if it is page 1 then go back to some state of page1 and so on.

Comment: I'm using `data-ui-sref=""` for navigating through the pages. And I cant use conditions becuz user may visit any page at any time resulting navigation wont be appropriate. 
If any page is visited 3-4 times, i dont want to repeat them while going back. It should go to repeated pages only once.